# Downsides of using own iPhone for company development

Tags: ios, iphone

What happens when you do the Development Provisioning Profile thing on your own device? Could it leak any of your personal information? Does it give the company any control over your device?

Is it something that you can be do without any problems using your own device, or should you just tell the company to buy devices that will only be used for development?

Answer (score 0):

It wont leak any information and it wont give info to company but here when you are adding device means company can see the device details in **member center**. Without registering device you cant use right? So I dont understand your perspective but if doing anything beyond the company's is not good.

Answer (score 0):

Could it leak any of your personal information?

*No, it will ask for your permissions for any data: photo/contacts/location etc*

Does it give the company any control over your device?

*No*

Each app runs in it own sandbox environment inside of the phone. And it can't access any data without your confirmation.